# C++ can native type char hold End of File character?

Tags: c++, char, eof

The title is pretty self explanatory.

```
char c = std::cin.peek(); // sets c equal to character in stream
```

I just realized that perhaps native type char can't hold the EOF.

thanks,
nmr

Comment: Can you post more of your post-edit loop? Testing the eof flag is usually not the best way to code an input loop. It is usually much better to check the return value of `peek()` (or much more usually `get()`?) as many people make the mistake of assuming that `eof()` will return true when the next read is going to fail. It also means that you are not going to detect any other failure apart from end-of-file and may loop indefinitely with bogus data.

Comment: You're good on the eof front because you 'peek' before the loop and at the very end of the loop, but you're still have problems with any non-eof error. I still think that it's simpler and avoids duplication if you just test the return value of `get()` in the while condition. Using `get()` means you don't have to 'ignore', and you can just pass the read character straight to the 'extensible character array'. Also for maximum portability you should do `ch = std::istream::traits_type::to_char_type( cin.get() );` instead of an implicit conversion to char, although this will work most of the time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer: No. Use **int** instead of **char**.

Slightly longer answer: No. If you can get either a character or the value **EOF** from a function, such as C's **getchar** and C++'s **peek**, clearly a normal **char** variable won't be enough to hold both all valid characters *and* the value **EOF**.

Even longer answer: It depends, but it will never work as you might hope.

C and C++ has three character types (except for the "wide" types): **char**, **signed char** and **unsigned char**. Plain **char** can be signed or unsigned, and this varies between compilers.

The value **EOF** is a negative integer, usually -1, so clearly you can't store it in an **unsigned char** or in a plain **char** that is unsigned. Assuming that your system uses 8-bit characters (which nearly all do), **EOF** will be converted to (decimal) 255, and your program will not work.

But if your **char** type is signed, or if you use the **signed char** type, then yes, you can store -1 in it, so yes, it can hold **EOF**. But what happens then when you read a character with code 255 from the file? It will be interpreted as -1, that is, **EOF** (assuming that your implementation uses -1). So your code will stop reading not just at the end of the file, but also as soon as it finds a 255 character.

Comment: Depends if you open the file as reading as a ascii file or a binary file. Though from memory I've never needed to open a file as ASCII allways as binary. This forgoes all the problems with EOF and what people define as EOF. Though my defintion of EOF is not when the ASCII document declares EOF but when you do reach the end of file size.

Comment: @Chad: I think you're thinking of something else here. If you open a file as text or as binary doesn't change how the value EOF is stored in a char variable.

Comment: @Thomas: just one minor detail: EOF is always negative, and *usually* -1, but the standard allows other negative numbers.

Answer (score 4):

Note that the return value of `std::cin.peek()` is actually of type `std::basic_ios<char>::int_type`, which is the same as `std::char_traits<char>::int_type`, which is an `int` and not a `char`.

More important than that, the value returned in that `int` is not necessarily a simple cast from `char` to `int` but is the result of calling `std::char_traits<char>::to_int_type` on the next character in the stream or `std::char_traits<char>::eof()` (which is defined to be `EOF`) if there is no character.

Typically, this is all implemented in exactly the same way as `fgetc` casts the character to an `unsigned char` and then to an `int` for its return value so that you can distinguish all valid character values from `EOF`.

If you store the return value of `std::cin.peek()` in a `char` then there is the possiblity that reading a character with a positive value (say ÿ in a iso-8859-1 encoded file) will compare equal to `EOF` .

The pedantic thing to do would be.

```
typedef std::istream::traits_type traits_type;

traits_type::int_type ch;
traits_type::char_type c;

while (!traits_type::eq_int_type((ch = std::cin.peek()), traits_type::eof()))
{
    c = traits_type::to_char_type(ch);
    // ...
}
```

This would probably be more usual:

```
int ch;
char c;

while ((ch = std::cin.peek()) != EOF)
{
    c = std::iostream::traits_type::to_char_type(ch);
    // ...
}
```

Note that it is important to convert the character value correctly. If you perform a comparison like this: `if (ch == '\xff') ...` where `ch` is an `int` as above, you may not get the correct results. You need to use `std::char_traits<char>::to_char_type` on `ch` or `std::char_traits<char>::to_int_type` on the character constant to get a consistent result. (You are usually safe with members of the basic character set, though.)

Comment: I appreciated this answer but it was a little more verbose than I was looking for and somewhat confused me.

Comment: Can you point to bits that could usefully be cut out or things that I can clarify? The goal of SO is to collabaratively get to the 'best' answers so any help improving is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not questioning the lucidity of the statements I was more so referring to my own ignorance of the language.  I truly just am not familiar enough with C++ to the point where you answer immediately clicked with me.

I guess I should have clarified at the beginning of my question that I wasn't concerned as much with portability.

Comment: I think this is a good answer, and (for C++) more correct in the details than mine. But it does get a bit complicated, because C++ is a complicated language. I mean, std::char_traits<char>::to_char_type!